# SheetJS xlsx-style cell style in excel is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, xlsx

I want to set different baground color for each cell in xslx in angular4.
But no style effect appear on excel.Is there any solution?
My code is below.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const wb = {SheetNames: [], Sheets: {}};
    const ws_name = 'Report';
    /* create worksheet: */
    const ws: any = {};
    /* the range object is used to keep track of the range of the sheet */
    const range = { s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: 0, r: 0 } };

    /* Iterate through each element in the structure */
    for (let R = 0; R < data.length; R++) {
      if (range.e.r < R) {
        range.e.r = R;
      }
      for (let C = 0; C < data[R].length; C++) {
        if (range.e.c < C) {
          range.e.c = C;
        }
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        const cell = { v: data[R][C], s: { alignment: { textRotation: 90 }, font: { sz: 16, bold: true, color: '#FF00FF' }, fill: { bgColor: '#FFFFFF' } }, t: 's' };
        if (cell.v == null) {
          continue;
        }
        /* create the correct cell reference */
        const cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R });
        /* determine the cell type */
        if (typeof cell.v === 'number') {
          cell.t = 'n';
        } else if (typeof cell.v === 'boolean') {
          cell.t = 'b';
        } else {
          cell.t = 's';
        }
        /* add to structure */
        ws[cell_ref] = cell;
      }
    }
    ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    const wscols = [
      { wch: 4 }, // "characters"
      { wch: 3 },
      { wch: 20 },
      { wch: 45 },
      { wch: 13 },
      { wch: 30 },
      { wch: 15 },
      { wch: 5 },
      { wch: 20 },
      { wch: 3 },
      { wch: 15 },
      { wch: 15 },
      { wch: 12 },
      { wch: 75 }
    ];

    ws['!cols'] = wscols;
    wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
    /**
    * Set worksheet sheet to "narrow".
    */
    ws['!margins'] = { left: 0.25, right: 0.25, top: 0.75, bottom: 0.75, header: 0.3, footer: 0.3 };
    wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
    const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
      type: 'binary',
      bookSST: true,
      bookType: 'xlsx',
      cellStyles: true
    });
    saveAs(new Blob([this.s2ab(wbout)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'report.xlsx');
```

I installed both xlsx and xlsx-styles.

npm install xlsx ,
    npm install xlsx-style

Any one can help me to find the solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const XLSTYLE = require('xlsx-style');` While writing the workbook instead of using `XLSX`. Try Using `XLSTYLE`.

Comment: @VipulSingh, This package is not working in the front-end application (Angular). I got the error like "Can't resolve module fs".